I got error saying result of string concatenation is too long
I am trying to insert data into table which have values more than 4000 character, to overcome with this i have made column qcnotes datatype clob on zzz_drop_result_718001 but i couldn't get it done.
DECLARE 
    GRPNM VARCHAR2(100); 
    CLOBNOTES CLOB;
BEGIN 
    DELETE ZZZ_DROP_RESULT_718001;
    COMMIT;
    FOR REC IN (select a.* ,length(QCnotes)notelength from (
    SELECT
                      To_char(SYSDATE,'MM/DD/YYYY') LOGGEDDATE,
                      'DROP IN RECENT MONTH' CATEGORY,
                      upper(a.GRPNAME)GROUPNAME,
                      To_Char(a.SOURCES) PAYER,
                      DECODE(a.FLAG,'CURR_RX','RXCLAIMS','CLAIMS' )FLAG,
                      case
                        when Nvl(b.FLAG,a.FLAG) in ('CURR_CLAIMS','CURR_RX') then 
                        dmbs_lob.substr('Drop seen in this processing only. Day count for recent paid month is ' ||a.paid_day_cnt|| ' covering paid dollars of $'||a.paid||' contributed by file' ||To_Char(a.srcfilenames)||'.',4000,1)
                        when b.source_cnt > a.source_cnt then 
                        dbms_lob.substr('No of payer contributing to recent month has decreased compared to previous processing.',4000,4001)
                        when abs(a.paid_day_cnt - b.paid_day_cnt) <= 3 then 'Day count for recent paid month is '||a.paid_day_cnt||' similar to previous processing covering paid dollars of $'||a.paid||' contributed by file '||To_Char(a.srcfilenames)||'.'
                        else 'Day count for recent paid month is '||a.paid_day_cnt||' covering paid dollars of $'||a.paid||' contributed by file ' ||To_Char(a.srcfilenames)||' while day count for previous recent paid month was '||b.paid_day_cnt||' covering paid dollars of $'||b.paid||' contributed by file '||To_Char(b.srcfilenames)||'.'
                      END as QCNOTES ,
                      '' AS ATTATCHMENT,
                      case
                        when Nvl(b.FLAG,a.FLAG) in ('CURR_CLAIMS','CURR_RX') then 'Y'
                        when To_Char(b.sources) like '%,%' and To_Char(a.sources) not like '%,%' then 'N'
                        when abs(a.paid_day_cnt - b.paid_day_cnt) <= 3 then 'N'
                        else 'Y'
                      END as QCCONCERN
                 from
                      tab1 a
                LEFT join
                      tab2 b
                on
                    a.grpname = b.grpname
                and
                    SUBSTR(a.FLAG,INSTR(a.FLAG,'_')+1,LENGTH(a.FLAG)) = SUBSTR(b.FLAG,INSTR(b.FLAG,'_')+1,LENGTH(b.FLAG))
                    ) a) 
    LOOP
    BEGIN
        IF REC.NOTELENGTH <= 3999 THEN      
            INSERT INTO ZZZ_DROP_RESULT_718001 (
                loggeddate, category, groupname, payer, datatype, qcnotes, ATTACHMENT, QCCONCERN
            ) VALUES (
                REC.LOGGEDDATE, REC.CATEGORY, REC.GROUPNAME, REC.PAYER, NULL, REC.QCNOTES, REC.ATTATCHMENT, REC.QCCONCERN
            );
            commit;
        ELSIF length(substr(rec.qcnotes,4000,rec.notelength))<=3999 then 
            Dbms_Output.PUT_LINE('Note length too long: ' || REC.GROUPNAME);
            
            clobnotes:=substr(rec.qcnotes,4000,rec.notelength);
REC.QCNOTES);
            
            GRPNM := REC.GROUPNAME;
            INSERT INTO ZZZ_DROP_RESULT_718001 (
                loggeddate, category, groupname, payer, datatype, qcnotes, ATTACHMENT, QCCONCERN
            ) VALUES (
                REC.LOGGEDDATE, REC.CATEGORY, REC.GROUPNAME, REC.PAYER, NULL, CLOBNOTES, REC.ATTATCHMENT, REC.QCCONCERN
            );
            COMMIT;
            update ZZZ_DROP_RESULT_718001 set qcnotes=qcnotes||clobnotes where groupname=grpnm;
            commit;
        END IF;
        EXCEPTION WHEN OTHERS THEN Dbms_Output.PUT_LINE('Note length too long: ' || REC.GROUPNAME);
    end;
    END LOOP;
END;

got error:
Error report -
ORA-01489: result of string concatenation is too long
ORA-06512: at line 7
ORA-06512: at line 7
01489. 00000 -  "result of string concatenation is too long"
*Cause:    String concatenation result is more than the maximum size.
*Action:   Make sure that the result is less than the maximum size.
I want to insert data with more than 4000 character, i tried using substr and break and insert but it is not working. I have tried using dbms_lob,xmlagg,listagg.
First part of if statement will be executed and inserted successfully but the other part shows error of string concatination is too long.

https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/23/refrn/MAX_STRING_SIZE.html

Please [edit] the question and include a [MRE] with: the CREATE TABLE and INSERT statements for some sample data that replicates your problem and will allow us to run your code; an English (not code) explanation of the logic that you are trying to implement; and the expected output for your sample data. At the moment we need to try to reverse engineer the requirements from the code and guess what you are trying to do and it makes the question very difficult to answer.

The second line of the error trace is ORA-06512: at line 7 but line 7 is FOR REC IN (SELECT * FROM zzz_vw_recentdrop) and there is no string concatenation on that line. Are you using views? If so, make sure you include the DDL for the view and the underlying tables; if not, which row is actually generating the error?

@MT0 yeah i created view, now i have modified the query , string concatenation is on qcnotes section where i get multiple source file name exceeding 3999 characters.

You have an XY-problem. You are asking about the issues with the INSERT code but the issue is actually with SELECT * FROM zzz_vw_recentdrop as zzz_vw_recentdrop is a view and is raising the exception and not your later code (but that doesn't mean that you shouldn't simplify your code as I show below). You could effectively delete this question and ask a new question about how to fix the view as the code in this question is tangential to the error and you need a more focused question on just the view.

If you are going to ask the question here then you should rollback your previous edit and include the DDL statement for the view zzz_vw_recentdrop and for the underlying tab1 and tab2 tables (assuming that they are tables) rather than trying to merge the view into your existing code which invalidates the existing answer.

@Bohemian I've updated the dupe target because the one you linked to didn't offer a solution to this question (the only similarity was the error message, the question was asking about a hierarchical query with an effectively unsolvable problem).

You probably want to ensure that the strings you are concatenating are concatenated into a CLOB which means either prepending EMPTY_CLOB() or wrapping the first literal you are concatenating to in TO_CLOB().
Like this:
CREATE VIEW zzz_vw_recentdrop
select a.*,
       length(QCnotes) AS notelength
from   (
  SELECT SYSDATE AS LOGGEDDATE,
         'DROP IN RECENT MONTH' AS CATEGORY,
         upper(a.GRPNAME) AS GROUPNAME,
         To_Char(a.SOURCES) AS PAYER,
         DECODE(a.FLAG,'CURR_RX','RXCLAIMS','CLAIMS' ) AS FLAG,
         case
         when Nvl(b.FLAG,a.FLAG) in ('CURR_CLAIMS','CURR_RX')
         then EMPTY_CLOB()
              || 'Drop seen in this processing only. Day count for recent paid month is '
              || a.paid_day_cnt
              || ' covering paid dollars of $'
              || a.paid
              || ' contributed by file'
              || a.srcfilenames
              ||'.'
         when b.source_cnt > a.source_cnt
         then EMPTY_CLOB()
              || 'No of payer contributing to recent month has decreased compared to previous processing.'
         when abs(a.paid_day_cnt - b.paid_day_cnt) <= 3
         then EMPTY_CLOB()
              || 'Day count for recent paid month is '
              || a.paid_day_cnt
              || ' similar to previous processing covering paid dollars of $'
              || a.paid
              || ' contributed by file '
              || a.srcfilenames
              ||'.'
         else EMPTY_CLOB()
              || 'Day count for recent paid month is '
              || a.paid_day_cnt
              || ' covering paid dollars of $'
              || a.paid
              || ' contributed by file '
              || a.srcfilenames
              ||' while day count for previous recent paid month was '
              || b.paid_day_cnt
              || ' covering paid dollars of $'
              || b.paid
              || ' contributed by file '
              || b.srcfilenames
              || '.'
         END as QCNOTES ,
         NULL AS ATTATCHMENT,
         case
         when Nvl(b.FLAG,a.FLAG) in ('CURR_CLAIMS','CURR_RX')
         then 'Y'
         when To_Char(b.sources) like '%,%' and To_Char(a.sources) not like '%,%'
         then 'N'
         when abs(a.paid_day_cnt - b.paid_day_cnt) <= 3
         then 'N'
         else 'Y'
         END as QCCONCERN
  from   tab1 a
         LEFT join tab2 b
         on a.grpname = b.grpname
            and SUBSTR(a.FLAG,INSTR(a.FLAG,'_')+1,LENGTH(a.FLAG)) = SUBSTR(b.FLAG,INSTR(b.FLAG,'_')+1,LENGTH(b.FLAG))
) a


Thank you for your answer, empty_clob() really helped me.

You appear to be over-complicating things trying to use loops and can simply use a single INSERT ... SELECT ... statement:
BEGIN 
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'TRUNCATE TABLE ZZZ_DROP_RESULT_718001';

  INSERT INTO ZZZ_DROP_RESULT_718001 (
    loggeddate, category, groupname, payer, datatype, qcnotes, ATTACHMENT, QCCONCERN
  )
  SELECT LOGGEDDATE, CATEGORY, GROUPNAME, PAYER, NULL, QCNOTES, ATTACHMENT, QCCONCERN
  FROM   zzz_vw_recentdrop;

  COMMIT;
END;
/

fiddle

Thank you for your answers. But it is not that simple, i have above 10,000 character in qcnotes field coming from my concatenation, so above query throws the same error.

I understand your concern, stackoverflow didn't let me post all the long query so i created view to reduce the length of code and make it more read able, above you can see i have provided the query which i used to create a view. Problem is in QCNOTES concatenation section where sourcefilenames are dynamically concatenated.  I hope this will answer your concern and made somehow clear about my issue.
